# How can I meter power usage by an on-demand electric hot water heater?

Tags: electrical, water-heater, meter

I am installing a radiant heat system alongside a rocket mass heater.  I want to compare the cost of operating each.  For the radiant heat system, an on-demand electric hot water heater is being used.  I want to meter power used by this device as a way to quantify the cost of operating it.

The heater will be hard-wired and operates on split-phase 240v at 19A.  What's the best way to meter its actual power usage?

Comment: Google [electric sub-metering](https://www.google.com/search?num=40&safe=off&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS590US590&hl=en-US&ei=zTwyWKbyJOe3jwSh_LHYDA&q=electric+sub-meter&oq=electric+sub-m&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.0.0j0i22i30k1l4.3684.3684.0.7547.1.1.0.0.0.0.115.115.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.1.114.KH51SZ9wy-k)

Comment: There are many products available.  I'm not confident in my ability to select the right one for my project.  A little bit of hand-holding would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a [120/240 Volt Pass-Through kWh Meter, 3-wire (2 hots, 1 neutral), 100A, 60Hz, EKM-25IDS](http://www.ekmmetering.com/basic-kwh-meter-100a-120-240-volt-3-wire-60hz-ekm-25ids.html).

The meter is hard-wired in front of the hot water heater and provides a digital kWh readout for the hot water heater's power usage.